# Adjusting the alignment of a set of equations

Tags: equations, alignment, ieeetrantools

I wanted to adjust the alignment of two equations but I didn't know which environment to use.

So I found online the `IEEEtrantools` package that did exactly what I wanted except for the numbering of the equation.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage[skip=1.5\baselineskip, indent=0pt]{parskip}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
I
\begin{document}
    \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{cCl}
    \ket{\psi}=\int \dd^3{x} \ket{x} \braket{x}{\psi} &\qquad &\text{in the $\ket{x}$ basis} \\
    \ket{\psi}=\int \frac{\dd^3{p}}{(2\pi\hbar)^3} \, \ket{p} \braket{p}{\psi} &\qquad &\text{in the $\ket{p}$ basis}
    \end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I wanted to center the equations and align to the left the text which is exactly what it did.

So I have a few questions:

- Could I have done the same with an `amsmath` environment (`align`, `gather` ...)?
- How do I put only one centered numbering for my equations in this environment?
- Where can I find the documentation for this package? Because when I search on the CTAN site, all I find is an old text document that explains nothing and refers to mostly non-existent documents.

Comment: If the documentation you're looking for is that for `amsmath`, if you have a full TeX Live installed, you should be able to type "texdoc amsldoc" at a command line prompt and get it.  If you don't have texdoc, go to https://texdoc.org and enter a request there in the form.  On CTAN, search for "amsmath" and choose the "latex-amsmath" package for the current version.

Comment: If you're looking for an introduction to the `IEEEeqnarray` environment that's provided by the `IEEEtrantools` package, I suggest you consult section 3.4.5, "IEEEeqnarray Environment`, of [The Not So Short Introduction to LATEX](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort-letter.pdf) by Tobias Oetiker and others.

Comment: An [introduction](https://moser-isi.ethz.ch/docs/typeset_equations.pdf) to the `IEEEeqnarray` by Stefan M. Moser.

Answer (score 4):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={cl},column{1}={rightsep=2em},column{Z}={cmd=\text}}
\ket{\psi}=\int \dd^3{x} \ket{x} \braket{x}{\psi}                          & in the $\ket{x}$ basis \\
\ket{\psi}=\int \frac{\dd^3{p}}{(2\pi\hbar)^3} \, \ket{p} \braket{p}{\psi} & in the $\ket{p}$ basis
\end{tblr}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You asked,

> Could I have done the same with an `amsmath` environment (`align`, `gather`, ...)?

Short answer: Yes.

Longer answer: The following solution employs an `aligned` environment, which is provided by the `amsmath` package. The `aligned` environment is encased in an `equation` environment, which ensures that the entire expression gets associated with a single equation number.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage{amsmath, physics}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\ket{\psi} 
   &= \int \dd^3{x} \ket{x} \braket{x}{\psi} 
   & \quad 
   & \text{in the $\ket{x}$ basis} \\
\ket{\psi} 
   &= \int \frac{\dd^3{p}}{(2\pi\hbar)^3} \ket{p}\braket{p}{\psi} 
   & \quad 
   & \text{in the $\ket{p}$ basis}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```